# Getting SQLite DELETE LIKE result

Tags: c++, sqlite

I want to delete several rows from a table by using DELETE LIKE query in C++. I know how to do it and it works. But also I want to know which rows were actually deleted. Is there a way to do it via 1 query or it is impossible and the only way to do it is 
1. SELECT LIKE 
2. DELETE LIKE

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to SELECT -> DELETE you could also use a TRIGGER.

The following example shows/demonstrates a relatively generic way (a little inefficient as such) for both :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable_deletions;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable_deletions2;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS mytable_deletions_trigger;

/* MAIN TABLE */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, mydata TEXT);

/* CREATE TABLES TO RECORD DELETIONS (first for 1. select->delete the other for 2. trigger)*/
/* Note that these are created based upon the source table, with an additional column srowid so as to be able to definitively delete rows (extra column may not be needed) */
CREATE /*TEMP option? */ TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable_deletions AS SELECT 0 AS srowid,* FROM mytable WHERE mydata <> mydata;
CREATE /*TEMP option? */ TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable_deletions2 AS SELECT 0 AS srowid,* FROM mytable WHERE mydata <> mydata;
/* Create the BEFORE DELETE Trigger */
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS mytable_deletions_trigger BEFORE DELETE ON mytable
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO mytable_deletions2 SELECT rowid AS srowid,* FROM mytable WHERE rowid = old.rowid;
    END
;
/* LOAD TESTING DATA */
INSERT INTO mytable (mydata) VALUES('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E');

/* CLEAR PREVIOUS DELETIONS */
DELETE FROM mytable_deletions;
DELETE FROM mytable_deletions2;

/* 1. RECORD DELETIONS PRIOR AND DELETE ACCORDING TO RECORDED DELETIONS */
INSERT INTO mytable_deletions SELECT rowid AS srowid,* FROM mytable WHERE mydata >= 'C';
/* DO THE ACTUAL DELETIONS (will fire trigger 2.) */
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE rowid IN (SELECT srowid FROM mytable_deletions);


/* Display results from TRIGGER */
SELECT * FROM mytable;
SELECT * FROM mytable_deletions;
SELECT * FROM mytable_deletions2;

/* CLEANUP */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable_deletions;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable_deletions2;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS mytable_deletions_trigger;
```

Running the above results in :-

Remaining data :-

[image]

Deleted Rows (select->delete)

[image]

Deleted Rows (trigger)

[image]